# Pass parameters between functions in Python Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to build an application(using Flask) which basically takes a form, sends to user the form content for preview and publishes the content if user feels ok. If user disapproves the preview, she should be able to go back and edit the form, with original data there.

Basically the structure is

```
@app.route('/edit')
def edit():
    ...
    #return rendered page for form inputting
    #the form action triggers preview()
@app.route('/preview')
def preview():
    ...
    #return rendered page for preview
    #one button triggers publish()
    #one button redirect to edit() and send back the form information
@app.route('/publish')
def publish():
    ...
    #write content to database
    #redirect to view()
@app.route('/')
def view():
    ...
    #rendered page for viewing contents
```

The question is how should I pass the content back and forth. I think I can

1. create a global variable in app.py and change it through different functions
2. create a temporary file(txt or database, etc) to store information

I think both will work, but are they good or efficient enough? What is the professional way to do this?

Comment: I would avoid having 2 separate pages for edit and preview, unless you are actually doing more than simply passing the content from one to the next. You can consider leaving the content on the client until the user is satisfied with the result.

Comment: You can include a form on the preview page. It can either be a hidden form with different elements used to present the preview or a read-only form presented to the user.

Comment: @njzk2 I think it's a good point. I can use javascript to realize that.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go the globals way, because then your Flask app would be *keeping state*, as in that information is now contained in the Flask process, and visible only within it. So if you happen to spawn several web processes, you will get different versions of the global vars. Also, if that process crashes/restarts the information is all gone.

You want to have this in something that is made to **explicitly keep state**, like a datastore (e.g. RDBMS, NoSQL etc) or at the very least some sort of "cache" server that is centralized to all your Flask processes.

The content you are previewing will live on the datastore, be presented on the form, and will have some sort of ID in the datastore (e.g. a primary key in a RDBMS) that you can pass around your Flask app.